# Running hyperledger composer playground locally causes an Error

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

[image]I am working on a tutorial on Hyperledger Composer (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-interact-extend-local-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer/index.html). It uses docker to run local version of hyperledger composer playground.

The first time I ran it on localhost 8080, it worked fine, but then a few days later but I run it, it throws an error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'engine' of undefined

This is what I see on the command line:

> [2018-03-16 05:40:53] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
>   [2018-03-16 05:40:53] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-playground id:0
>   [2018-03-16 05:40:53] PM2 log: App name:composer-playground id:0 online
>   PlaygroundAPI           :createServer()           > 8080, false
>   PlaygroundAPI           :createServer()                     Playground API started on port 8080
>     PlaygroundAPI           :createServer()           <
>   Composer                :main()                   >
>     PlaygroundAPI           :createServer()           Client with ID 'zIhEA8HiUwbYafauAAAA' on host '::ffff:172.17.0.1' connected 
>   ConnectorServer         :constructor()            > {"fs":{"constants":{"O_RDONLY":0,"O_WRONLY":1,"O_RDWR":2,"S_IFMT":61440,"S_IFREG":32768,"S_IFDIR":16384,"S_IFCHR":8192,"S_IFBLK":24576,"S_IFIFO":4096,"S_IFLNK":40960,"S_IFSOCK":49152,"O_CREAT":64,"O_EXCL":128,"O_NOCTTY":256,"O_TRUNC":512,"O_APPEND":1024,"O_DIRECTORY":65536,"O_NOATIME":262144,"O_NOFOLLOW":131072,"O_SYNC":1052672,"O_DSYNC":4096,"O_DIRECT":16384,"O_NONBLOCK":2048,"S_IRWXU":448,"S_IRUSR":256,"S_IWUSR":128,"S_IXUSR":64,"S_IRWXG":56,"S_IRGRP":32,"S_IWGRP":16,"S_IXGRP":8,"S_IRWXO":7,"S_IROTH":4,"S_IWOTH":2,"S_IXOTH":1,"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1,"UV_FS_COPYFILE_EXCL":1,"COPYFILE_EXCL":1},"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1},"thenifyFs":{"constants":{"O_RDONLY":0,"O_WRONLY":1,"O_RDWR":2,"S_IFMT":61440,"S_IFREG":32768,"S_IFDIR":16384,"S_IFCHR":8192,"S_IFBLK":24576,"S_IFIFO":4096,"S_IFLNK":40960,"S_IFSOCK":49152,"O_CREAT":64,"O_EXCL":128,"O_NOCTTY":256,"O_TRUNC":512,"O_APPEND":1024,"O_DIRECTORY":65536,"O_NOATIME":262144,"O_NOFOLLOW":131072,"O_SYNC":1052672,"O_DSYNC":4096,"O_DIRECT":16384,"O_NONBLOCK":2048,"S_IRWXU":448,"S_IRUSR":256,"S_IWUSR":128,"S_IXUSR":64,"S_IRWXG":56,"S_IRGRP":32,"S_IWGRP":16,"S_IXGRP":8,"S_IRWXO":7,"S_IROTH":4,"S_IWOTH":2,"S_IXOTH":1,"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1,"UV_FS_COPYFILE_EXCL":1,"COPYFILE_EXCL":1},"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1},"rimrafOptions":{"constants":{"O_RDONLY":0,"O_WRONLY":1,"O_RDWR":2,"S_IFMT":61440,"S_IFREG":32768,"S_IFDIR":16384,"S_IFCHR":8192,"S_IFBLK":24576,"S_IFIFO":4096,"S_IFLNK":40960,"S_IFSOCK":49152,"O_CREAT":64,"O_EXCL":128,"O_NOCTTY":256,"O_TRUNC":512,"O_APPEND":1024,"O_DIRECTORY":65536,"O_NOATIME":262144,"O_NOFOLLOW":131072,"O_SYNC":1052672,"O_DSYNC":4096,"O_DIRECT":16384,"O_NONBLOCK":2048,"S_IRWXU":448,"S_IRUSR":256,"S_IWUSR":128,"S_IXUSR":64,"S_IRWXG":56,"S_IRGRP":32,"S_IWGRP":16,"S_IXGRP":8,"S_IRWXO":7,"S_IROTH":4,"S_IWOTH":2,"S_IXOTH":1,"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1,"UV_FS_COPYFILE_EXCL":1,"COPYFILE_EXCL":1},"F_OK":0,"R_OK":4,"W_OK":2,"X_OK":1,"disableGlob":true},"storePath":"/home/composer/.composer/cards"}, {}, [object Object]
>   ConnectorServer         :constructor()            <

I am running on:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem :/ First time it worked fine but next time, an engine of undefined. any solution?

**EDIT:**

I manage to make it works again, just run composer-playground with sudo privileges. That solves my problem. Hope it helps!